# How to create all different combination undirected graphs with sum of any two adjacent vertices equal to prime numbers

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, backtracking

How to create all different combination undirected graphs with sum of any two adjacent vertices equal to prime numbers. The number set is [1….10]

example:-
undirected graph for number set [1...4]

```
 1------2     2)   3---2
 |      |           |
 |      |           |
 4      3           4
                    |
                    |
                    1
```

appreciate  your help.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no unique solution to this problem in the way you put it. In this case should there be any solution, all solutions... ??

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Thanks for the Reply. i want all solutions( different combinations of undirected graphs).

Comment: I'm not sure if asking a mathematician how to do it, then trying to code it, then in case of troubles asking here, is not a better idea.

Comment: @user3160055 I've described a general approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

All possible (undirected) edges are:

1-2, 1-4, 1-6, 1-10, 2-3, 2-5, 2-9, 3-4, 3-8, 3-10, 4-7, 4-9, 5-6, 5-8, 6-7, 7-10, 8-9, 9-10

All possible graphs are subsets of this set of edges. There's 18 edges, so there's 2<sup>18</sup> possible graphs.

Answer (score 0):

From a high level, your algorithm looks something like this:

1. Construct the set of all permitted edges by iterating over all the pairs of distinct numbers in your set of vertices and testing if they sum to a prime.
2. Construct the set of all permitted graphs by taking all possible subsets of the set of permitted edges.

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach you can reform your problem as follows: find all possible prime numbers which can be generated as sum of values from `[k..n]` (`k<=n`). After finding all those combinations you have to take all possible subsets of those combinations. So your solution will be the set of all those subsets.

In pseudo code:

- Step1: generate a
  [Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) of prime
  numbers from `k` to `(k+n+1)(k+n)/2`(sum of all numbers from `k` to
  `n`)
- Step2: check for every prime if it can be generated as sum of the
  numbers you have. Store every possible combination. You can write a
  recursive function to do it.
- Step3: find all subsets of the set generated from combinations in
  Step2.
- Step4: output all those subsets.